# The attribute to set the visibility of a connector in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

In the Enterprise Architect it's possible to **hide** a **connector** in a specific diagram. Developing an Add-in (Extension), I need to perform such action by "**code**", but I cannot find the corresponding attribute of the connector/diagram class.

I'd appreciate it if anybody could help finding the relevant **attribute** for setting the **visibility** of a connector.

Comment: How do you perform this manually? (not programmatically)

Comment: By a "right click" on the connector, there is a menu item named "Visibility". There it is possible to hide the connector manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connector is not hidden universally, but in a specific diagram. Thus, the visibility is not a property of the `Connector` class, but of the `DiagramLinks` class, which holds the representation of one connector in one diagram. (Yes, the class is called DiagramLinks with an 'S'.) In `DiagramLinks` you'll find the property `IsHidden`.

So what you need to do is:

1. Retrieve the `Connector` you want to hide/show, and the `Diagram` you want to show/hide it in.
2. Traverse the `Diagram.DiagramLinks` collection, whose constituent type is the `DiagramLinks` class.
3. Find the `DiagramLinks` instance where `Connector.ConnectorID` matches `DiagramLinks.ConnectorID`.
4. Set `DiagramLinks.IsHidden` to `True` (or `false` to unhide).
5. Call `DiagramLinks.Update()`. You may also need to call `Diagram.Update()`.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the 5 steps:

1. Retrieve the Connector you want to hide/show, and the Diagram you
   want to show/hide it in.
2. Traverse the Diagram.DiagramLinks collection, whose constituent type
   is the DiagramLinks class.
3. Find the DiagramLinks instance where Connector.ConnectorID matches
   DiagramLinks.ConnectorID.
4. Set DiagramLinks.IsHidden to True (or false to unhide).
5. Call DiagramLinks.Update(). You may also need to call   Diagram.Update().

but i've to add a 6th to see the effect on the current diagram:
Repository.RefreshOpenDiagrams(true);

Comment: Downvoted: this isn't a separate answer but an enhancement of an existing one, and should therefore go in a comment on that answer.

Comment: @Uffe ..but for commenting you need the reputation of 50 (http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) so roberto could not do it